# converting HTML with custom css fonts(@face-fonts) to image

Tags: flying-saucer

I need to convert html with custom css fonts(@face-fonts) to image.I have evaluated html2image and flying-saucer but both fail to convert custom css font.

Below is the css font in html.

> @font-face{font-family:'FuturaBT';src:url(../fonts/FuturaBT.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype")

Answer (score 0):

`flying saucer` requires `ttf`. I am not sure if `eot` is supported.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, and I DO have format("truetype") and a ttf font. Actually I also tried to only keep that format, and still it doesn't work. I also checked my font file with FontForge for validity, and it seems to be valid.